# I switched PhD programs after a month, do I mention this on my CV?

Tags: phd, cv

More detail: After a failure of communication, I turned down other funded offers to accept an unfunded PhD. I had some money saved and tried it out anyway, but after *one month* quit and went with a previous offer (after telling them I'd made a bad decision)!

I worked for 3 months specifying my skills for the defaulted PhD, do I mention the experience on my CV? On one hand I don't want the blip recorded as it leaves a little time gap between finishing MSc and entering PhD and records my bad decision making, on the other the institute name is a major buzzword for careless recruiters. Thoughts?

Comment: If you just state years, and not months, surely you can omit the first PhD position without there being an evident gap?

Answer (score 1):

**I think you should not bother mentioning the first (unfunded) PhD program.**

From your post (emphasis added):

> After a failure of communication, I turned down other funded offers to accept an unfunded PhD. I had some money saved and tried it out anyway, but **after one month quit** and went with a previous offer (after telling them I'd made a bad decision)!

Since you only spent a month in this PhD program, I can't see how it is really relevant to your experience, nor will it result in a significant gap in your CV if you omit it. Moreover, you probably do not have many achievements from this month, so it is more likely to just result in unnecessary questions when people read your CV.

> I worked for 3 months specifying my skills for the defaulted PhD, do I mention the experience on my CV?

What do you mean by "specifying my skills"? This could be a good thing to mention if you were working on, e.g., online coursework, but you don't need to mention that it was for the PhD that you quit.

On the other hand, if it was just you working on skills on your own, then it won't help to mention it.

> On one hand I don't want the blip recorded, on another it leaves a little time gap between finishing MSc and entering PhD

How long is the gap of time? If it's just a few months, it will be ignored. If it is a full year, it may be something you will want to explain to someone if they ask, but I don't think it will be necessarily critical.

> and the institute name is a major buzzword for careless recruiters.

I am not sure I understand why it would be a "buzzword" -- is it a poorly regarded institute? Anyway, combining this concern together with all your other reservations, I think it would be fine to leave it off.

Comment: "Buzzword" in the sense that oxbridge holds amplified weight in prestige focused industry and some startups

Comment: @Jordan OK, I see. So you take that as a reason to include it, not to omit it?

Comment: A frail reason, sure

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience says **don't**.
Similar to you, my CV included a semester of irrelevant PhD studies. It helped me a lot to find a position after I removed that part completely.

If you mention some unfinished business, then the question

> Why did you quit/dropped off?

is inevitable. This is not because people want to come down on you, but the thought is

> If the candidate mentioned this piece of information, **which is
>   obviously useless**, it must have a reason.

Then, it is not very helpful for your interview process if you don't give a satisfying answer. So, *in my personal opinion*, I suggest you leave that period out, and answer only if you are asked about what you did in that month.

Answer (score 0):

While it is a bit of a grey area, I'd suggest that it isn't necessary to do so as it hasn't contributed to your qualifications for the future.

You need to be able to give an explanation for the gap if asked, of course. But not everyone's education trajectory is a smooth and unbroken upward curve and people understand that. As people we aren't perfect and we suffer setbacks. Having made a poor decision isn't career ending and you have wisely found a better path.

People change programs for lots of reasons.

However, if you decide that you should list it, I doubt that there would be any downside. It will probably guarantee a discussion about why, but that is fine also. "I made a mistake and worked to correct it" is a pretty human response.

While it isn't precisely the definition, a CV normally lists accomplishments, not setbacks. Long gaps are suspect, of course and can be explained or not.